# Create overlay for DIV inside overflow:hidden DIV without clipping

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, overflow

[image: diagram showing div layout I'd like]

Hi all. I'd like to be able to highlight a div inside a container DIV that has overflow:hidden  set (changing this is not an option).  I'm using the CSS 'outline' and 'box-shadow' properties to do this.  The issue is that when the DIV is the full size of the outer div, you can't see that it's selected as the outline is (unsurprisingly) clipped to the outer div.  Also, if the inner div is against one of the edges the issue occurs.

The attached images shows the layout of the divs, red is the outer div, purple the 'outline' and black the DIV I want to highlight - in that example the purple highlight to the left is clipped.

So the question is, is there a way (JavaScript & jQuery are fine) of overlaying the black div with another div such that (a) the overlay div isn't clipped to the outer div, and (b) when the black div moves or is resized, the overlay moves/resizes with it?

**EDIT: It looks like this simply isn't possible in HTML/CSS in the way I described.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set theblack div to "positon:relative". Then put the outline into that div, and set it with "position:absolute". With top,left,with and height you can put it "around" the black div.

Edit:

Sry, the black div has to be position absolute, too. Working example see here:
http://jsfiddle.net/t94FV/

Comment: Thanks Flo. Unfortunately the 'purple div' still gets clipped to the outer div using this techinque - unless I missed something.

Comment: Cheers Flo. Sadly that method prevents the black div being clipped too - what's happening is that the black div is being positioned relative to the body, not the red div. Try setting the left or top of the black div in your jsfiddle (e.g. to left: 0; top: 0;) .. :-(  Thanks for trying though!

Comment: There was some useless stuff that wasn neccesary.. look here: http://jsfiddle.net/4AXpV/

Comment: Thanks - though again the black div isn't clipped to the red one. I'm thinking that what I want (black div absolutely positioned, and clipped to the red div) is not possible if the overlay div is positioned INSIDE the red div. I think it has to be outside - but then I'll need to keep the two divs in sync somehow.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use margins with percentages.

Answer (score 0):

The trick is in only parent cover div with relative position. No `position:relative` children of `overflow:hidden` div. Only parent!

```
<div class="trick-container" style="position:relative">
    <div class="overflow-hidden" style="overflow:hidden">
        <div class="no-relative-position-1">
            <div class="no-relative-position-2">
                <div class="no-relative-position-N">
                    <div class="position-absolute" style="position:absolute"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```